# Compiling mruby for STM32F407 cortex-m4 target

Tags: gcc, embedded, arm, mruby

I'm trying to compile mruby for the STM32F407 cortex-m4 target, but i get the following error when running `./minirake` in the repo directory:

```
Command Failed: ["/home/eugenio/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld" 
 -T "/home/eugenio/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/share/gcc-arm-none-eabi/samples/ldscripts/mem.ld" 
 -o "build/arm-none-eabi/bin/mrbc" 
 "build/arm-none-eabi/tools/mrbc/mrbc.o" 
 "build/arm-none-eabi/lib/libmruby_core.a" ]`
```

What am I doing wrong? The toolchain is the one from launchpad the git repo is up to date and googling around didn't help.

Complete stacktrace is at [stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/zfa8THYH)

Build_config file for mruby is at [buildconfig](http://pastebin.com/CNM0pPXm)

Comment: Ok, thanks alot @bill-pringlemeyer, I suspected that. About verbosity of rake, it's already on, since I invoked it with -v option and piped all the output to  file. The file is at stacktrace link on pastebin. Thanks to your suggestion I removed all floating point options from gcc flags and most of the errors are gone. Now i get these [errors](http://pastebin.com/HLjC2H42) 
My current gcc flags are : `-mtune=cortex-m4 -march=armv7-m -mthumb -nostdlib`

Comment: Now it appears you aren't linking with the 'C' library.  Why did you change to `-nostdlib`?  That will do this.